# Is it ok for a child class to convert a concrete method back to abstract?

Tags: scala

In scala (or perhaps, in general) is it ok to have a concrete implementation that is later forced into a more abstract method? For example

```
trait Tree {
  def print(s:String) = println(s)
}

trait Leaf extends Tree {

  def print(s:String) // force use of this to be defined later. Maybe I need the word override?

}
```

This contrived example demonstrates something I've never really considered using before, which is to start concrete but expand abstract. In reality I've build a tree-like class structure that can handle most of the concrete code until it hits various leaf classes, at which point I don't want to accidentally forget to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "unimplement" a method. Using your example, one can define

```
class Foo extends Leaf
```

without any complain of the compiler, meaning that all classes deriving from your Tree trait will have the `print` method already implemented.

You can provide a default implementation and still make sure that you don't use it everywhere by using two traits

```
trait Tree {
  def method() // abstract method
}

trait DefaultImpl {
  def method() = {
    // default implementation
  } 
}

// now you can do things like

class Foo extends Tree with DefaultImpl // this will use the default implementation

class Bar extends Tree // this will not compile until you provide an implementation for method
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't occur to me that 2 traits was the solution

Comment: What if one wishes to force concrete classes to change the implementation? More precisely,  I wish to create a trait 'ClassWithReasonableToStringMethod'